# Redirecting stdout/stderr of a child process to a file

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, child-process

I have a Python script (`popen.py`) which runs another Python script (`counter.py`) as a child process with the output redirected to `/tmp/counter.log`. The code I am using is:

**/tmp/counter.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import time

i = 0
while True:
    print i
    i +=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

**/tmp/popen.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import subprocess

f = open("/tmp/counter.log", "a+")
p = subprocess.Popen("/tmp/counter.py", stdout=f, stderr=f, bufsize=1)
```

However when I run `popen.py` the child process is created and stays running, however nothing get written to `/tmp/counter.log` until the output reaches 4096 bytes, then it appears to be flushed to the file.

**Is there any way I can get my child process to write to the logfile line-by-line without modifying the `counter.py` script itself?**

The reason I don't want to modify `counter.py` is that the child process may not always be running a Python script. I've tried the same thing running a small executable (written in C) and the same problem occurs.

I have tried writing a self-flushing wrapper for the file and using that for `stdout` as described [here](http://tech.xster.net/tips/python-log-stdout-to-file/) but that doesn't work either.

I've done some debugging with `lsof` and `strace` and this is what I've managed to find out:

### lsof (file descriptors)

**Running /tmp/counter.py manually**

```
COMMAND PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
python2 629 daniel    0u   CHR  136,0      0t0      3 /dev/pts/0
python2 629 daniel    1u   CHR  136,0      0t0      3 /dev/pts/0
python2 629 daniel    2u   CHR  136,0      0t0      3 /dev/pts/0
```

**Running /tmp/counter.py via /tmp/popen.py**

```
COMMAND PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
python2 638 daniel    0u   CHR  136,0      0t0      3 /dev/pts/0
python2 638 daniel    1u   REG  202,0        0    768 /tmp/counter.log
python2 638 daniel    2u   REG  202,0        0    768 /tmp/counter.log
```

### strace (system calls during the while loop)

**Running /tmp/counter.py manually**

```
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
write(1, "11\n", 3)                     = 3
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
write(1, "12\n", 3)                     = 3
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
write(1, "13\n", 3)                     = 3
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
write(1, "14\n", 3)                     = 3
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
write(1, "15\n", 3)                     = 3
```

**Running /tmp/counter.py via /tmp/popen.py**

```
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
...
write(1, "11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n"..., 4096) = 4096
```

Comment: You don't seem to use the `communicate` method of your `Popen` instance. Also, in `counter.py`, how about writing to `sys.stdout` directly and then flushing?

Comment: @LukasGraf That does indeed work. Is there anyway I can achieve this purely in the code? I'd like to not have to manually specify it in the invocation line of `Popen` or by editing `counter.py`.

Comment: @Midnighter I don't need to use `communicate` because I don't want to communicate with the child process, and in my question I clearly mentioned that I want to be able to do this without changing `counter.py`.

Comment: @DanielGibbs You can't change the buffer settings of a file in another process.  Without changing `counter.py` you could start that script with an Python interpreter and the `-u` (unbuffered) option.

Edit: Alternativly set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environtment variable before starting the `counter.py`.

Comment: The docs for [`Popen()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) say setting `bufsize` to 0 means unbuffered, which I think is what you want.

Comment: I've tried that. In the same fashion that I've tried setting it to 1 for line buffering, but neither works.

Comment: @BlackJack But what if the other process is a binary executable? I have the same problem then: when run normally it prints to standard out as expected, but when I try to redirect to a file, it buffers.

Comment: @DanielGibbs AFAIK there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up using, which does not fully solve the problem, but is the most acceptable compromise at this point, is to set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable while spawning a child process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import subprocess

f = open("/tmp/counter.log", "a+")
p = subprocess.Popen("/tmp/counter.py", stdout=f, stderr=f, env={
    "PYTHONUNBUFFERED": "Yes please"
})
```

This has the lowest overhead in terms of extra code and additional processes, but only works if the child process is a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't get processes to write line-by-line into a file unless the process flushes at regular intervals. But you can make the calling process look like a terminal. Processes that follow CLIB rules will switch to line mode and give you what you want. In this example, I setup as a pseudo terminal and write + flush the log file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import os
import subprocess
import pty

master,slave = pty.openpty()
f = open("/tmp/counter.log", "a+")
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "counter.py"], stdout=slave, stderr=slave, close_fds=True)
os.close(slave)
reader = os.fdopen(master)
while True:
    data = reader.readline()
    if not data:
        break
    f.write(data)
    f.flush()
    print data.strip()
print 'done'
reader.close()
p.wait()
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look at that terminal stuff, but your example as it stands isn't quite what I want, as I want the parent process to terminate after spawning the child.

Comment: This example could be morphed into an intermediate executor. The parent calls this script which calls the child script. Parent exits, but this script remains.

Comment: So for every child process I end up with two?

Comment: @DanielGibbs - yes. If that's a problem, you could get fancy with some sort of babysitting program that runs many subprocesses. But in the simple case, you'd have 1 babysitter for each child. And it could get more complicated - read up on the daemon module for the best way to let programs run in the background.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, subprocess.Popen can be used for executables other than Python scripts. Here's a snippet that creates a copy of the user's cron schedule:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

def getTempCrontabFile(argTmpFile='/tmp/tmpFile'):
    # Create a file in r/w mode that will be the target for
    # the crontab utility redirection.
    try:
        tmpFile = open(argTmpFile, 'a+')
    except IOError as customErr:
        print 'Failed to open or create temporary crontab file.'
        print customErr
        return customErr
    # Define the command line to list the cron schedule.
    cmdLine = 'crontab -l'
    # Format the command line into an array of arguments. This is
    # useful for proper formatting of spaces and quoted arguments
    # especially when commands get complicated.
    args = shlex.split(cmdLine)
    # Make the call to Popen using the file we created for stdout.
    result = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=tmpFile)
    return result
```

Comment: Yes I know that. This does not answer my question.